How to Set Frontend of OSRM?
I'm new to OSRM . I have setup the containers for Backend and Frontend of OSRM but unfortunately cannot access the coordinates on MAP. And can't select the Start and End point on the Map.
Followed the official document of OSRM having Docker image but still having issues accessing frontend.
Tried doing changes in Leaflet_options.js but still no change in UI.

I had similar issues.
Here is working OSRM frontend with Docker https://github.com/evgeniyarbatov/osrm-frontend
Hope it helps!
